# Wifi Range Extender using Ethernet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, ethernet

I want to improve the network speed in my room. The wifi signal can be awful at times but the room has a dedicated ethernet port in the wall which provides much faster speeds.

My computer is a MacBook Air however, so it doesn't have an ethernet port.

I found this Wireless Range Extender with an ethernet port on the bottom. [https://www.amazon.co.uk/TL-WA850RE-Universal-Extender-Configuration-UK/dp/B00AHXXJVW/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1480250143&sr=8-1&keywords=tp+link+wifi+extender](https://www.amazon.co.uk/TL-WA850RE-Universal-Extender-Configuration-UK/dp/B00AHXXJVW/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1480250143&sr=8-1&keywords=tp%20link%20wifi%20extender)

In the setup guides they demonstrate being able to plug an ethernet port from the Wireless Range Extender into one of your devices that needs a wired connection.

My quesiton is, do Wireless Range Extenders let you plug one end of the ethernet cable into the wall and the other into the extender?

My theory is that doing so would enable me to get a wireless connection in my room that's as fast as if I plugged the computer directly into the ethernet plug in the wall.

I'm hoping this means I can avoid having to swap the ethernet cable from one device to the next each time I want to use the Internet.

Am I completely wrong? Or will this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is an Access Point. Most of them (if not all of them) bridge the wireless with the Ethernet interface. I guess that the product that you linked can do that.